# Is it safe to enable the guest_enable feature in vsftpd?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

Based on the vsftpd configuration document, if we set 'guest_enable' configuration to 'YES' it will classify every non-anonymous login as the guest user which is defined in 'guest_username' So it means we won't find out which local user has logged in? Is it safe?

Comment: Doesn't `guest_username` specify *the* local user? I know little about `vsftpd` (and therefore it's not an answer), but from the documentation I infer `guest_enable=YES` activates additional layer of *virtual* users. They log in, but from the point of view of the OS the whole setup belongs to a local user specified by `guest_username`. Any separation of virtual users is the job of `vsftpd`, the OS may help by allowing `chroot` or something. But virtual users mean nothing to the OS. Again, I know little about `vsftpd`. Investigate further or wait for an answer from someone who really knows it.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know more about vsftpd, I can say enabling 'guest_enable' will increase the security since it makes it possible to have virtual users who are the users that can only login to ftp service and not into ftp server. so it makes your ftp service more secure than letting all users login to your ftp server as a local user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).